# Mac OSX 10.10 how to recover data

Tags: macos, data-recovery

To my greatest stress I did following today 
sudo rm -rf * tmp/ instead of sudo rm -rf tmp/* from home folder. And ta-da everything is gone from my home directory. Unfortunately I dont have time machine backup either. Can anyone suggest best recovery software for this situation?

Comment: go to a nice coffee place and relax. there is nothing you can do other the reinstalling the OS X. you know that the rm is final and terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still using the same computer, your chances of recovery go down with each minute of operation - recovering deleted files is time-consuming, recovering over-written files is impossible. And your computer is constantly writing things to disk.

Restart the deleted machine in target disk mode and connect it to another mac. Get a copy of Data Rescue 3 and use it in deleted-files mode. You will also need alternate storage equal to the original drive size.

After it's done recovering things you get to rename everything. The filenames are gone (overwritten) at the time of deletion, your stuff will be recovered with sequential names (Image001.jpg, Image002.jpg etc.)

And I don't think we have to do the usual lecture on backups. Point is well made?

Comment: Thanks! I think my chance went away when I restarted my laptop minute after. It re-initialized my home directory so it probably overwrote Direcotry info. I anyway bought Recovery software but its useless. All the data recovery softwares sites I visited doesn't tell you immediately to stop using ur lost or damage disk/computer or at least be aware of what can happen. I know not everyone deletes their entire Home folder but it's responsibility of such software to spread awareness on what not to do.  Anyway I gave my laptop to professional repair shop.